# What purpose does the .gitignore file serve in Symfony 4?

Tags: git, symfony, gitignore, symfony4

I have noticed that Symfony Composer automatically creates a `.gitignore` file in a new project. However, I can't find anything about a `.gitignore` file in Symfony's documentation.

What is the purpose of this file, how does it relate to Symfony, and what should it contain?

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking.  Create a new project with website-skeleton and you will get a .gitignore which covers the main issues.  I typically have to make a slight tweak to exclude some IDE files.  But otherwise you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the .gitignore file is not specifically for Symfony. This is used for all projects with which git is used for versioning.
I recommend this to you https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore but in general, we use .gitignore this way (With Symfony):

```
### Ignore what is contained in a directory
### Example the vendor folder
/vendor/

### The change made to a file
### Example the .env environment file
.env

### I created a new directory called "save" and I want to ingon
/path/to/my/save/folder/
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Symfony Flex, your .gitignore file will be updated based on the receipe of your package. That's means that most of the time you don't have to worry about the .gitignore file except if you add yourself a folder that should be excluded (for example, a public/media folder with some dynamic added images)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this project as a base.
It is not absolute, but it is a guide to understand and then adjust as necessary.

https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Symfony.gitignore